# Match Key in a Dict to a String

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

Hello beautiful people!

```
dict = {'Awesome' : 'Sauce', 'Foo' : 'Barr'}

Col A Col B
1     'This is Awesome'
2     'I really foo him'
```

I'm trying to find the most pythonic way to iterate over a data set/frame and return *any* string matches with the value of the dict.

so for number 1 i'd like to return Sauce in column c for example, and 2 'barr' in the respective row but in col c.

I'm dealing with an csv / excel file if that matters.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm happy to use the Pandas and NP library.

Edit for Wen:

```
ID     Name of Course
0      Super Event Training: English Event...
1      Start with our Maths Training...
2      Live online Biology Training...
3      Maths throughout time...
4      Online Q&A Webinar: History..
5      Start with our Creative ...
6      Spring Conf with Author
7      Physics in our age ...
8      Spring Conf
9      Start with our educational items...
10     Education delivery in India...
11     English IELTS, Access to University..
12     Our Core Products for Empowerment..
```

I have a DF like this that goes on for about 500 rows that I'm scraping with the help of an API, I need to transform this free form text into values that are in my dict. What I've done is identified key words that I've put into my key values and assigned to the dict values, so we can analyse the data.

Perhaps using a dict is not the best way to do this? any advice would be much appreciated.

DN.

Comment: one small tips do not name a dict as dict ...

Comment: I was such a newb here, this was my first week or so trying out pandas and python! @Wen-Ben - just came back to use this piece of code, thanks dude =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can using python only

```
[''.join(z) for z in [[y[1] if y[0] in x  else '' for x in df['Col B'] ] for y in d.items()]]
Out[22]: ['Sauce', 'Barr']
```

Comment: this worked brilliantly! any idea how I would append the values to the matching row on a dif column?

Comment: that was my first move, but I got this error back : Length of values does not match length of index

Comment: @Datanovice can you print the length of the list and the length of the df

Comment: I was only testing as my work laptop is at work but the file will contain an x amount of rows and say, 40 columns. The data is from a web scrape/api service that i'm testing and I need to align the data for our databases. (it's for a NFP charity if that makes you feel better about helping :D)

Comment: hey buddy, edited my answer for you, hopefully my issue is clear!

Answer (score 2):

So if you can read in the csv line by line (or split it to where you can access the values in column b) The below will give you a list of all values in the sentence in column B that match a key in the dictionary.

```
word_dict = {'Awesome' : 'Sauce', 'Foo' : 'Barr'}
s1 = 'This is Awesome'
matches = [x for x in s1.split() if x in dict.keys()]
>> matches = ['Awesome']
```

It works by using `string.split()` to split the sentence into words. Then the list comprehension iterates over the resulting word list and checks if it is a key in the dictionary, if it is a key, it is added to a new list, if not a key it is ignored.

Comment: Ah! The answer seems so simple and elegant, thank you ! I'm mobile right now but will test this at home!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
def get_col3(text,d):
    ret = ""
    keys = list(d.keys())
    vals = list(d.values())
    for key in keys:
        if key.lower() in text.lower():
            idx = keys.index(key)
            ret+=vals[idx]+" "
    return ret

d = {'Awesome' : 'Sauce', 'Foo' : 'Barr'}

text1 = 'This is Awesome'
text2 =  'I really foo him'
text3 =  'That was Awesome foo to him'

print(get_col3(text3,d))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explicitly iterate over the dictionary and the Dataframe, you can use:

```
mapper = {'Awesome' : 'Sauce', 'Foo' : 'Barr'}

data = {"Col B": ["This is Awesome", "I really foo him"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for item in mapper:
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if item.lower() in df["Col B"].iloc[i].lower():
            print(mapper[item])
```